# How to create 'empty' object with desired field

Tags: python, object

For test purposes I need to create something like an empty object with some particular fields. Let me clarify by example:

Currently there is a structure:

```
var = {
    'blas': {
        'bla':       0.250,
        'bla1':        0.300,
        'bla2': 6,
        ...
    },
    'somth1': self.smth1,
    'something': [
        { 'h1': 66.00 },
        { 'h2': 47.00 },
        { 'h3': 85.00 },
        { 'h4': 32.00 },
        { 'h5': 34.00 }
    ],
    'this_has_to_be_object'.field: 1
}
```

The thing I want is for `'this_has_to_be_object'` to be an actual object to which I can add some fields and set values. The objective of such behaviour is to test another function that operates with `'this_has_to_be_object'.field`.

Comment: Why not just create an empty dictionary or that value then? Or do you need something that supports arbitrary attributes instead of keys?

Comment: It seems ("For test purposes...") that he's constructing dummy data to send to some code for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namedtuples are on way, if they don't have to be mutable:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MyTupleType = namedtuple('MyTupleType', ['field'])

yourobject = MyTupleType(field=3)

print(yourobject.field)  # prints 3
```

If it's for testing, then using the Mock library is also handy (see http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/ ; `unittest.mock` is part of the standard library since Python 3.3 as well).

```
yourobject = MagicMock()
yourobject.field = 3
```

Note that yourobject now has *any* field or method you try to access on it, and their values are all yet another MagicMock instance. It's a very powerful unit testing tool.

Lastly you can just create a boring dummy class:

```
class Dummy(object):
    pass

yourobject = Dummy()
yourobject.field = 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've taken a MagickMock()-way as a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
var = {
'blas': {
    'bla':       0.250,
    'bla1':        0.300,
    'bla2': 6,
    ...
},
'somth1': self.smth1,
'something': [
    { 'h1': 66.00 },
    { 'h2': 47.00 },
    { 'h3': 85.00 },
    { 'h4': 32.00 },
    { 'h5': 34.00 }
],
'this_has_to_be_object':{'field': '1'}
```

}

this is already a object, if you said `you want to add some field inside` you can do it like

```
...this_has_to_be_object.newField = 3;
```

isn't this what you want?

Comment: Yes, thank you - it's exactly what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a **Default dict** here.e.g.

```
var  = defaultdict(int)

var.update({
    'blas': {
        'bla':       0.250,
        'bla1':        0.300,
        'bla2': 6,
        ...
    },
    'somth1': self.smth1,
    'something': [
        { 'h1': 66.00 },
        { 'h2': 47.00 },
        { 'h3': 85.00 },
        { 'h4': 32.00 },
        { 'h5': 34.00 }
    ],
    'this_has_to_be_object'.field: 1
}
)
```

Now var['anything'] would always return with 0.

I guess that is the functionality you require for testing, Right ?

Comment: It looks like so. I've chosen a MagickMock as the solution since it's more suitable here. Thank you!